# My model is being controlled by only half its armature

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, parent

I custom made a human make model and then made the armature to match. It has IK knees as well. To make the right half of the body, I copied the left and then scaled it so that the left armature flipped to be the right. After that, I tried to parent the armature and model using automatic weights. It worked, but when I go into pose mode, the right half does nothing and the left half warps the right half of the body.

What can I do to make my rig work?[image]

Comment: If you made it with a mirror modifier you might need to apply it.

Comment: "it" as in the model or the armature?

Comment: Nvm, it worked! I just had to apply the mirror to my mesh. Thanks